# How to show ProgssBar when internet connection not avaliable?

Tags: android, jsoup, android-webview

I am working an Android app. When internet connection is not avaliable app closes. I have used few method for solve this problem, but i can't.  I have searched in Google more forums, bur can't find. Maybe you can solve this problem.

In app uses `Webview` and `Jsoup` parser. I give you all MainActivity code for good understanting.

```
  @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);


    webview= (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview1);
    webview.getSettings().setCacheMode( WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK );
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);

    webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

            new MyAsynTask().execute(url);
            return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
        }

    });

    new MyAsynTask().execute(this.url);
}


@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
    startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
    return true;

}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();


    if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {

        url="http://hut.az/arenda-kvartir/";
        webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

                new MyAsynTask().execute(url);
                return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
            }

        });

        new MyAsynTask().execute(this.url);


    } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

        url="http://hut.az/prodaja-kvartir/";
        webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

                new MyAsynTask().execute(url);
                return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
            }

        });

        new MyAsynTask().execute(this.url);


    } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

        url="http://hut.az/novostroyki/";

        webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

                new MyAsynTask().execute(url);
                return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
            }

        });

        new MyAsynTask().execute(this.url);

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}

private class MyAsynTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Document > {
    @Override
    protected Document doInBackground(String... urls) {

        Document document = null;
        try {

            document= Jsoup.connect(urls[0]).get();
            document.getElementsByClass("header1").remove();
            document.getElementsByClass("topbar clearfix").remove();
            document.getElementsByClass("mapandslider").remove();
            document.select("div#right_sidebar").remove();
            document.select("div#left_sidebar").remove();
            document.getElementsByClass("footer1").remove();
            document.getElementsByClass("copyright").remove();



        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

       this.ShowMess();
        }
        return document;
    }
          public  void ShowMess(){

                progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
                progressDialog.setTitle("Internet Baglantisi Yoxdur !");
                progressDialog.setMessage("Zəhmət olmasa gözləyin...");
                progressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                progressDialog.show();

          }

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        progressDialog.setTitle("Yüklənir");
        progressDialog.setMessage("Zəhmət olmasa gözləyin...");
        progressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        progressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Document document) {

        super.onPostExecute(document);

        webview.loadDataWithBaseURL(url,document.toString(),"text/html","utf-8","");
        progressDialog.dismiss();

    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
use following method: 
  private boolean checkNetwork() {
        boolean wifiDataAvailable = false;
        boolean mobileDataAvailable = false;
        ConnectivityManager conManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo[] networkInfo = conManager.getAllNetworkInfo();
        for (NetworkInfo netInfo : networkInfo) {
            if (netInfo.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("WIFI"))
                if (netInfo.isConnected())
                    wifiDataAvailable = true;
            if (netInfo.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("MOBILE"))
                if (netInfo.isConnected())
                    mobileDataAvailable = true;
        }
        return wifiDataAvailable || mobileDataAvailable;
    }

where you want to show progressbar.
if(!checkNetwork()){
    show progressbar or you want to show toast also like no internet connection avilable please try again
}
else {
your task you want
}
```

Comment: where you want to show your progressbar in activity or fragment. inside  oncreate. also do your work in else.

Comment: copy whole the code checkNetwork(){} ,  paste it in your activity. after that 
take  progressbar, initilaze it then use it (use it in if condition) and call method(checkNetwork) in onCreate method like if(!checkNetwork()){ show ur progressbar}else{do operation that you want to perform} .